# multi-tenant native app registration

Tags: azure, native, multi-tenant

I am looking to build a UWP app that can access user profile data via the Graph api.

I thought I would start simple and see if I could get a sample working. NativeClient-UWP-WAM (https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-uwp-wam/tree/master/NativeClient-UWP-WAM).

I ran the sample as is, without registering the App in our company AD. At the end of the day, I want users to be able to download my app from the store and run its with user consent only, and not require an Admin to register it.  I entered my company credentials and consented bu then received

> Something went wrong
>
> AADSTS50011 the reply address 'ms-webappx-web://Micosoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/S-.... does not match the reply address for the application {guid}

On inspection in the portal, the app has been automatically configured as an enterprise app, where appid is visible but not reply-uri,  but not set up as a registered app?

How can I get this to work WITHOUT manually registering in the portal? Remember I want joe public to be able to sign in/consent themselves on their own domains.

Has anyone run this example as multi-tenant without the apparently optional step 3 to register as single tenant?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you get that error, but the "enterprise app" in the Portal is the Service Principal created for the app in your tenant. It's the way multi-tenant apps work in Azure AD. The Application object is a template for the Service Principals which are created in each directory that consents to it.

The first user signing in must be an admin. There is no way for a regular user to consent to a new application in the tenant. Manual registration should not be necessary through portal though.

Comment: Thanks, I read about Service Principals and Apps. I would assume that the sample has already been App registered by the author in his tenant (hence that claim that you can run the code as is without registration), and that I would see a Service Principal entry - which I do. So leaves we wondering how I determine the correct reply uri and App ID